# Select and Saving values from listbox to SQL DB

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

Scenario:  We have a listbox in our MVC View and the user has the ability to highlight multiple values.  I'd like to be able to save those selected values(if possible?) as a comma delimited cell value in our '08 SQL Database.

The image below shows what I am attempting to explain. **Note the selection in the LISTBOX** Thanks in advance!

[image: View of Listbox selections]
This is where we save the passed in values from the Positionnumber DDL (Listbox w/ mulitple highlights).

```
> <HttpPost()>
>         Function Edit(wsmonitor As WSMonitor, ByVal vbpositionnumberDDL As Integer, ByVal PassedCounty As Integer, ByVal
> MonitorTypeDDL As String) As ActionResult
>             wsmonitor.PositionNumber = vbpositionnumberDDL
>             wsmonitor.MonitorType = MonitorTypeDDL
>             wsmonitor.county = PassedCounty
> 
>             If ModelState.IsValid Then
>                 db.Entry(wsmonitor).State = EntityState.Modified
>                 db.SaveChanges()
>                 Return RedirectToAction("Index")
>             End If
> 
>             Return View(wsmonitor)
>         End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the name field of your listbox matches the parameter in your Edit method.
Then, change the Type of the parameter vbpositionnumberDDL  to be a string array.

You will then get passed in an array with each selected iten in the list box.
It's then easy to convert that to your comma string.

My VB.NET isn't great, but I think this will work

```
Function Edit(wsmonitor As WSMonitor, ByVal vbpositionnumberDDL As **String()**, ByVal PassedCounty As Integer, ByVal
> MonitorTypeDDL As String) As ActionResult
```

You can join you string using

```
Dim foo = [String].Join(",", vbpositionnumberDDL )
```